# php put variable into string loaded from array

Tags: php, json, string, echo

i'm having a json file containing some strings for echoing.
Now i want to put variable contents between these strings e.g.:

```php
$event_config = json_decode(file_get_contents("event_config.json"), TRUE);

$output_string = $event_config['e_header']['e_welcome_text'];
$name = value_lookup("f_personalien_vorname");

echo("Hello {$name},<br>Thanks. We have just received your query<br>");
echo ($output_string);
```

This one works fine, `{$name}` is replaced correctly with whats stored in `$name`.

```php
echo("Hello {$name},<br>Thanks. We have just received your query<br>");
```

This version with the same string loaded from json isn't working. Instead of `{$name}` being replaced it just gets printed with the whole string.

```php
echo ($output_string);
```

For reference my json currently looks like:

```json
{
    "e_header": {
        "e_welcome_text": "Hello {$name},<br><br>Thanks. We have just received your query<br>",
        "e_information": "Some string"
    }
}
```

Does somebody have an idea about this?

Comment: I think what's confusing you is that JSON also uses double quotes. This won't make `$name` interpolate, to PHP that is just a string. It's not the same as explicitly writing it out.

Comment: Is there any workaround/solution for this?

Comment: You would have to perform a string replacement to get your variable value in.

Comment: Okay going to attempt this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
Thanks to [@El_Vanja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4205384/el-vanja) giving me this hint.
I changed my json to:

```json
{
    "e_header": {
        "e_welcome_text": "Hello {{name}},<br><br>Thanks. We have just received your query<br>",
        "e_information": "Some string"
    }
}
```

Note the double braces `{{name}}`.
Then came up with the following which is replacing the upper expression.

```php
$output_string = $event_config['e_header']['e_welcome_text'];
echo(str_replace('{{name}}', $name, $output_string));
```

Answer (score -2):

you should escape the quotes and append to have a variable pass.

```
$event_config = json_decode(file_get_contents("event_config.json"), TRUE);
$output_string = $event_config['e_header']['e_welcome_text'];
$name = value_lookup("f_personalien_vorname");
echo("Hello " . $name . ",<br>Thanks. We have just received your query<be>");
echo($output_string);
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what i mean due to the fact that 
`echo("Hello {$name},<br>Thanks. We have just received your query<br>");` 
is working correctly. My problem happens with 
`echo ($output_string);`

Comment: You're using `json_decode($a, TRUE)` which you would need to use `var_dump` with. So either use `var_dump($output_string) `or remove the `TRUE` parameter and use `echo($output_string)`. (Due to the nature of it being Associative.) From PHP.NET = "When true, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays; when false, JSON objects will be returned as objects. When null, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays or objects depending on whether JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY is set in the flags."

Comment: Okay, removed the TRUE.  
Now the return is an object but `echo($event_config->{'e_header'}->{'e_welcome_text'});` still gives me `{$name}`.

Comment: You have misunderstood the issue. The problem is that the string coming from JSON cannot be evaluated as an expression.

Comment: Hi @El_Vanja do you have an idea for this?

Comment: @El_Vanja Ohh, I see where I misunderstood. Apologies. I will take a look at this when I have a chance if it's not already answered by tonight.